# Accessing custom user information through query

Tags: django

So I have this game app and I'm going to list user scores. The query I was thinking of using was the following:

```
top_list = User.objects.filter().order_by('-score')[:10]
```

But this was before I implemented the actual custom field 'score' to user. So I looked at the [recomended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) way, and did the following:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0);
```

which made me realize that `score` won't be a field in User at all (if I've understood it right)? User will have a one to one relationship to UserProfile that in turn holds the score. So how do I get a list of top-ten users based on their scores in descending order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
User.objects.all().order_by('-userprofile__score')[:10]
```

Check [django doc for explanation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups) about field lookup using `__`.

Comment: is `all()` necessary?

Comment: No it's not, it doesn't matter, but I feel like OP was using `filter()` but doesn't do any filtering, having a `all()` makes it easier to understand.

Comment: Yeah I suppose the filter() was redundant :) By the way, userprofile should be in lower case even though the model is defined as UserProfile?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships `ManyToMany` and `OneToOne` are all using lowercase model name to refer.

Answer (score 1):

You can order by related fields ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by)):

```
top_list = User.objects.filter().order_by('-userprofile__score')[:10]
```